# How can I 'touch' a remote file over FTP?

Tags: c++, .net, file-upload, ftp

I have some software which periodically uploads data to a remote location. At the remote location (maintained by a customer or a supplier so somewhat out of my control), there's a script running which detects changes to file size or the last-modified time-stamp of a file and if it's changed, passes the updated information on to other systems.

If I want to trigger the remote server to pass that information on without deleting and then re-uploading the contents, is there a way I can just 'touch' the file to changed it's last-modified date?

I'm using [the EnterpriseDT FTP Pro (.net) module](http://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/doc/manual/api/index.html) to do the uploading from a C++/CLI application on a windows platform.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. Any chance you can get `ssh` access instead/as well?

Comment: No, this is just an FTP server.

Comment: There is no `touch` command in a typical FTP server. How about `rename x.dat y.dat; rename y.dat x.dat` - I'm not sure if that updates the timestamp tho'.

Comment: Problem with renaming the file is that I think renaming it would make it appear that a new file appeared and then disappeared which may well have other repercussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried resuming a transfer and transferring 0 bytes which appears to do exactly what I need. I've leave this Q/A up in case anyone else is interested in doing the same.